# LaserScanLayer overlapping when I subscriber the topic “/scan”

Tags: visualization, android-core, opengl, rosjava, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First step:

In PC (Ubuntu 14.04) , I ssh to the kobuki and bring up it with this command line

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup  minimal.launch --screen &
```

and then start the gmapping with this command line

```
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping.launch
```

then the Turtlebot is normal start.

Second step:

In PC ,start the new session in terminal，echo the "/scan" topic, scan data is well,but the problem like this.[Left side of laser scan visualization on android gets weird](http://answers.ros.org/question/91836/left-side-of-laser-scan-visualization-on-android-gets-weird/)

---

This is the LaserScanLayer code: [LaserScanLayer](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/blob/kinetic/android_15/src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/layer/LaserScanLayer.java)

Could you help me?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254727/laserscanlayer-overlapping-when-i-subscriber-the-topic-%E2%80%9C/scan%E2%80%9D/) by [Tony10012](https://answers.ros.org/users/27331/tony10012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [this](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/issues/251)

---

Originally posted by [Tony10012](https://answers.ros.org/users/27331/tony10012/) with karma: 56 on 2018-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0